# missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

first file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from public import login


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://mail.163.com/')

login.user_login(driver)


login.user_logout(driver)
```

second file call public.py

```
class login():

    def user_login(self,driver):
        driver.switch_to_frame('x-URS-iframe')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='j-inputtext dlemail']").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='j-inputtext dlemail']").send_keys('xxxxx')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='j-inputtext dlpwd']").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='j-inputtext dlpwd']").send_keys('xxxxxx')
        driver.find_element_by_id(r'dologin').click()

    def user_logout(self,driver):
        driver.switch_to_default_content()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(u'退出').click()
```

when I run the first code, showing ' missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'

Really don't know why.
Thank you very much if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not instantiating the login class

```
objLog = login()
```

then call the methods you wanted to from login class using `objLog`

Comment: or change like this login().user_login(driver)
login().user_logout(driver)